# Web3 batch request return undefined

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to call approve function for BNT and another ERC20 via BatchRequest.

First request works good, but second return undefined, the same if I swap order.

Also if I cancel first transaction, second works good.

```
wrapperApprove = async () => {

// GET DATA
const web3 = this.props.MobXStorage.web3
let batch = new web3.BatchRequest()
const amount = await this.calculateConnectorBySmartTokenAmount()
const tokenInfo = this.getInfoBySymbol()
const converterAddress = tokenInfo[1]
const connectorAddress = tokenInfo[2]

const bnt = this.props.MobXStorage.web3.eth.Contract(ABISmartToken, 
BNTToken)
const connector = 
this.props.MobXStorage.web3.eth.Contract(ABISmartToken, 
connectorAddress)

// MAKE BATCH REQUEST
batch.add(connector.methods.approve(
converterAddress,
this.props.MobXStorage.web3.utils.toWei(String(amount[1]))
).send.request({from: this.props.MobXStorage.accounts[0]}))


batch.add(bnt.methods.approve(
converterAddress,
this.props.MobXStorage.web3.utils.toWei(String(amount[0]))
).send.request({from: this.props.MobXStorage.accounts[0]}))

batch.execute()
}
```